# How to create a TwoWay data-binding proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have the following classes...

```
class ExpressionBinder<T>
{
    public Func<T> Getter;
    public Action<T> Setter;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return Getter.Invoke(); }
        set { Setter.Invoke(value); }
    }

    public ExpressionBinder(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter)
    {
        Getter = getter;
        Setter = setter;
    }
}

class ComparisonBinder<TSource, TValue> : ExpressionBinder<bool>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TSource instance;
    private TValue comparisonValue;
    private PropertyInfo pInfo;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ComparisonBinder(TSource instance, Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> property, TValue comparisonValue) : base(null,null)
    {
        pInfo = GetPropertyInfo(property);

        this.instance = instance;
        this.comparisonValue = comparisonValue;

        Getter = GetValue;
        Setter = SetValue;
    }

    private bool GetValue()
    {
        return comparisonValue.Equals(pInfo.GetValue(instance, null));
    }

    private void SetValue(bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            pInfo.SetValue(instance, comparisonValue,null);

            NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomerName");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string pName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adapted from surfen's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10003320/219838)
    /// </summary>
    private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> propertyLambda)
    {
        Type type = typeof(TSource);

        MemberExpression member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (member == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.",
                propertyLambda));

        PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.",
                propertyLambda));

        if (type != propInfo.ReflectedType &&
            !type.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expresion '{0}' refers to a property that is not from type {1}.",
                propertyLambda,
                type));

        return propInfo;
    }
}
```

My code using the `ComparisonBinder` class is as follows:

```
radioMale.DataBindings.Add(
    "Checked", 
    new ComparisonBinder<DataClass, GenderEnum>(DataObj, (x) => x.Gender, GenderEnum.Male), 
    "Value", 
    false, 
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

radioFemale.DataBindings.Add(
    "Checked",
    new ComparisonBinder<DataClass, GenderEnum>(DataObj, (x) => x.Gender, GenderEnum.Male), 
    "Value", 
    false, 
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

They allows me to bind many controls to the same property using an expression to generate the value for the control's bound property. It works beautifully from the control to the object. (If you want to see more about using this class and a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10002817/219838))

Now, I need to get the other way around. When I update my object (which will alter the result of the get expression) I need the bound control to be updated. I tried implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` but it didn't make any difference.

One odd thing: setting the controls `DataSourceUpdateMode` to `OnPropertyChanged` somehow stops me from changing the checked radio.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#.Net WinForms" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Ok! Won't do it again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick answer:

- You **HAVE TO** use binding source
- Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your object
- Make the proxy listen to the event above
- Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the proxy
- Filter the PropertyChanged events received from your object in the proxy and raise only when `((PropertyChangedEventArgs) args).PropertyName == pInfo.Name`
- Add the proxy to `BindSource.DataSource`
- Use the `BindingSource` to bind the control to your data object's property

## The final code

Available (along with other binding classes) at: http://github.com/svallory/BindingTools

### Classes

```
class ExpressionBinder<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Func<T> Getter;
    public Action<T> Setter;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected IList<string> WatchingProps;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return Getter.Invoke(); }
        set { Setter.Invoke(value); }
    }

    public ExpressionBinder(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter)
    {
        WatchingProps = new List<string>();
        Getter = getter;
        Setter = setter;
    }

    public ExpressionBinder(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter, ref PropertyChangedEventHandler listenToChanges, IList<string> propertyNames)
    {
        Getter = getter;
        Setter = setter;

        listenToChanges += SourcePropertyChanged;
        WatchingProps = propertyNames;
    }

    protected void SourcePropertyChanged(object obj, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null && WatchingProps.Contains(args.PropertyName))
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, args);
        }
    }

    protected PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource, TValue>(Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> propertyLambda)
    {
        Type type = typeof(TSource);

        var member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (member == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.",
                propertyLambda));

        var propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.",
                propertyLambda));

        if (type != propInfo.ReflectedType &&
            !type.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expresion '{0}' refers to a property that is not from type {1}.",
                propertyLambda,
                type));

        return propInfo;
    }
}

class ComparisonBinder<TSource, TValue> : ExpressionBinder<bool> where TSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly TSource instance;
    private readonly TValue comparisonValue;
    private readonly PropertyInfo pInfo;

    public ComparisonBinder(TSource instance, Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> property, TValue comparisonValue)
        : base(null, null)
    {
        pInfo = GetPropertyInfo(property);

        this.instance = instance;
        this.comparisonValue = comparisonValue;

        Getter = GetValue;
        Setter = SetValue;

        instance.PropertyChanged += SourcePropertyChanged;
        WatchingProps.Add(pInfo.Name);
    }

    private bool GetValue()
    {
        return comparisonValue.Equals(pInfo.GetValue(instance, null));
    }

    private void SetValue(bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            pInfo.SetValue(instance, comparisonValue, null);
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = new ComparisonBinder<MySourceObjClass, PropType>(
    MySourceObject, 
    p => p.PropertyToBind, 
    ValueToCompare);

rdBeSmart.DataBindings.Add(
    "Checked", 
    bs, 
    "Value");
```